# Perfect forwarding for returned value?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I'm overloading an `operator[]`:

```
const Type&& operator[](int index) const {
        if (index >= size) { std::cout << "Error: excessive index.\n"; return 0; }
        else if (index < 0) { std::cout << "Error: negative index.\n"; return 0; }
        else {
            Node* temp = head->next;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { temp = temp->next; }
            return temp->value;
        }
    }
```

But I need a duplicate of it, which will return non-const Type value. I read that we can use perfect forwarding for cases when arguments of function can be both const or non-const (so that we wrap them in `forward<Type>` every time we use it), but how to use it for value that is returned?

Also, if I simply want to return nothing, should I write `return 0;` or `return NULL;`? Which is more understandable?

Comment: return std::forward<temp_value_type>(temp->value); what about this?

Comment: @peco `nullptr` is a `NULL` for pointers, why would I want to return it?

Comment: yes  you are right

Comment: @peco but I don't know what to do with declaration of function `const Type&& operator[]`, I mean anyway I have to declare to functions: const and non-const.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need just to return a refernce? Perfect forwarding applies mostly to passing arguments and not returning. Also you write you need duplicate, how does that connect to perfect forawrding>

Comment: @miszcz2137 yeah, I actually had confused a little what perfect forwarding is needed for. I thought it's some thing to eliminate need of creating overloaded function duplicates, but more specifically it is a thing to make able to take both lvalue and rvalue references as parameters, so my question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It's connected to `const` only in the way that `const T&` can make the same job (to take both lvalues and rvalues), but it'll accept only `const` lvalues, so if you want non-const lvalues and rvalues, you should use forwarding reference `T&&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such unified syntax that would work for all, `const`/`volatile`/non-`const`/lvalue/rvalue/etc., implicit object parameters is currently not supported. However, there's the proposal [P0847r4: Deducing this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0847r4.html) which adds this functionality. With that, you could say:

```
template <typename Self>
auto&& operator[](this Self&& self, int index)
{
    if (index >= self.size) { throw std::out_of_range("Error: excessive index"); }
    else if (index < 0) { throw std::out_of_range("Error: negative index"); }

    auto* temp = self.head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { temp = temp->next; }        
    return std::forward_like<Self>(temp->value);
}
```

Until it becomes available, the best what you can do is to shorten the implementation for `const` and non-`const` overloads, and delegate both calls to a static helper function template, that actually *can* deduce the cv-qualification and value category of the implicit object parameter:

```
class List
{
private:
    template <typename Self>
    static auto&& get(Self&& self, int index)
    {    
        if (index >= self.size) { throw std::out_of_range("Error: excessive index"); }
        else if (index < 0) { throw std::out_of_range("Error: negative index"); }

        Node* temp = self.head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { temp = temp->next; }
        return temp->value;
    }

public:
    const Type& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return get(*this, index);
    }

    Type& operator[](int index)
    {
        return get(*this, index);
    }

private:
    // ...
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e153d2f714dd2fa1)

Also, note that the idiomatic approach for a function returning a reference is to throw an exception in case nothing can be returned, or to insert ad-hoc and return a new object.

Comment: Since I was looking for a clean & simple solution, I'll probably go with duplicates (as I don't see any performance improvements, and duplicates are easier to understand), but it was very interesting, thank you!

Comment: Woah, that new syntax looks funky.